# Link to PHP file from a HTML File

Tags: php, html

I have created an **header.html** includes file as a menu structure that i use in my **index.php.**

The problem is, when i click on the link in the **index.php** it directs it to the file with an *.html* extension - which actually does not exsist on the live server. On my live server, i get an Error 404 page as a result. When i type the URL with the correct extension (In that case: **PlayerReg.php**), it directs me to the correct adress and it works. But if i click on the link, i get the error Page.

This is the **index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<?php include("includes/head.html"); ?>
</head>
<header>
<?php include("includes/header.html"); ?>
</header>
<body>
 

    
</body>
</html>
```

This the **header.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="btn-styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Palanquin+Dark&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <title>Chess Team APP</title>
</head>

<header>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm animated-button sandy-one">Log-In</a> </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm animated-button sandy-two">Register</a> </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <a href="PlayerReg.php" class="btn btn-sm animated-button sandy-three">Register a new Player</a> </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm animated-button sandy-four">Learn more</a> </div>
      </div>
      
</header>
```

So on the site: http://codeplace.primebyte.ch/ when i click on the "Register A New Player" it should direct me to the registration form.

I made sure i uploaded the correct file via FTP.

I would like to add that the head.html file works just fine but there are no links included. I am not even sure if it makes sense that the head is included in the head.html and the header.html

Comment: You can't really have two `head` sections in a page. Why did you do that?

Comment: And you certainly should not have two ,`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">`s in a single page, that could really screw things up potentially.

Comment: It's because i am learning. But i thought it was an issue so i am not that useless as it seems :D

Comment: But my question is.. is that the problem so its not working ?

Comment: It's hard to tell, but it won't be helping. Does the same code work on the test server, but not on the live server? And are you saying that clicking on the link to playerreg.php causes you to be redirected to playerreg.html? It wasn't quite clear.

Comment: So local it does not work at all obviously. On the test server/live server i have this issue. 

Yes exactly. Clicking on "Register a new player" should direct me to PlayerReg.php but it directs me to PlayerReg.html but there is not even a html file like that on the server.

Comment: The file ```includes/header.html``` is not correct. try to find it on the server and update it with the new one. you can touch the file directly by the url https://codeplace.primebyte.ch/includes/header.html

Comment: `local it does not work at all obviously.`...why is that obvious? Most people would have a local webserver where they test stuff before deploying it to live

Comment: I mean local on my pc.. not on any server.

Comment: So what? You can run a development server on your local PC. A "server" isn't a piece of hardware, it's some software you install to provide a service. Like I said, that's how most people test their code during initial development. It's very time consuming to have to upload it somewhere else just for basic initial testing.

Comment: Yes i know that but i put it on our "live server" so i can share it here. It was easier.. I just use this subdomain for that stuff. ;)

Comment: Sure, but you don't ask a question here by sharing your live link, you do it by providing a [mre] of your issue within the question - which fortunately you did as well. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it for why your live link isn't useful or appropriate. Glad you got a solution below anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your markup to be valid using the combination of files that you have indicated you would need to modify your `index.php` page to be similar to the following:

In your code you are using `includes/head.html` etc means that the `includes` directory is a sub-directory of the current working directory (where the index.php page is) - if the files are located in a different directory they will not be included and will cause an error. By using `__DIR__ . '/includes'` you provide a full path for PHP to use to find the files and using `set_include_path` allows you to simply include the file by name once this path is set - small timesaver perhaps.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    set_include_path( __DIR__ . '/includes' );
    require 'head.html';
?>
    <body>
<?php
    require 'header.html';
?>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

As the HTML declaration and headers are all contained in `head.html` that should be the first content included.

#head.html

```
<!-- head.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="btn-styles.css" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="//fonts.googleapis.com" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="//fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
        <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Palanquin+Dark&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" /> 
        <title>Chess Team APP</title>
    </head>
```

As the `header` section is HTML content it should be within the body - so the `header.html` file should be included after the `body` has been opened.

#header.html

```
    <!-- header.html -->
    <header>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm animated-button sandy-one">Log-In</a></div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm animated-button sandy-two">Register</a></div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="PlayerReg.php" class="btn btn-sm animated-button sandy-three">Register a new Player</a></div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm animated-button sandy-four">Learn more</a></div>
          </div>
    </header>
```

when rendered in the browser this will yield:

```
<!-- head.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="btn-styles.css" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="//fonts.googleapis.com" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="//fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
        <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Palanquin+Dark&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" /> 
        <title>Chess Team APP</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- header.html -->
        <header>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm animated-button sandy-one">Log-In</a></div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm animated-button sandy-two">Register</a></div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="PlayerReg.php" class="btn btn-sm animated-button sandy-three">Register a new Player</a></div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm animated-button sandy-four">Learn more</a></div>
              </div>
        </header>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Everything is in the correct place

Comment: Seems like it worked. I tested it locally. Thanks a lot!